# Which species is proud of being conquered many times?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

I remember that in Star Trek (maybe Voyager?) a species was proud of having been conquered many times in their history.

What is the name of the species?

Comment: Are you thinking of a Tivolian from [Tivoli](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Tivoli) of the Doctor Who series? *'Tivoli was the most conquered planet in the galaxy. It was inhabited by a species of rodent-like humanoids. They were one of the oldest civilisations in the galaxy and simply let invaders do as they wished. Their anthem was "Glory To <Insert Name Here>" and their cities were designed to be comfortable for the invading armies.'*

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The **Mizarians**. Picard encounters one when he's kidnapped by aliens in [*TNG: Allegiance*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Allegiance_(episode))

> **PICARD:** *None? In the last three hundred years of Mizarian history, your planet has been conquered six times!*
>
> **THOLL:** *And we've survived by not resisting. Mizarians value peace above confrontation.*

---

> **Mizarians**
>
> *Planet: Mizar II. A highly intelligent and pacifistic race, so opposed to confrontation they have let themselves be conquered six times in the last 300 years. Humanoid in appearance but with whitish facial skin sharply folded along vertical lines.*
>
> <sub><sup>[StarTrek.Com - Profile.](https://intl.startrek.com/database_article/mizarians)</sup></sub>